# How can I convert Xlsx / Xls file to JSON file (eg. sample.json) Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, nodejs-server

[image]

I am trying to convert this excel sheet / file to json file as output not raw data (sample.json), I googled many resourses but I didn't find any working code or tutorials so I need some help, I have linked image that is excell data and how can I convert it into json file as below and upload it in MongoDB.

**sample.json**

```
{
"Sheet1": [
    {
        "Qusetion Number": "1",
        "Question": "A program language",
        "A": "defines the form of the instruction",
        "B": "is always machine dependent",
        "C": "is never machine dependent",
        "D": "All of the above",
        "E ": "None of the above",
        "Answers": "defines the form of the instruction"
    },
    {
        "Qusetion Number": "2",
        "Question": "Quiestion 2",
        "A": "Option A",
        "B": "Option B",
        "C": "Option C",
        "D": "Option D",
        "E ": "Option E ",
        "Answers": "Option C"
    },
    {
        "Qusetion Number": "3",
        "Question": "Question 3",
        "A": "Option 5",
        "B": "Option 6",
        "C": "Option 9",
        "E ": "Option9",
        "Answers": "Option 6"
    },
    {
        "Qusetion Number": "4",
        "Question": "Question 4",
        "A": "456",
        "B": "221",
        "C": "889",
        "Answers": "456"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Google search "xls to json npm" returns quite a few packages.

Comment: Tried many they returning raw data but I want data in json file

Comment: They return data in [json](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) format, than you can save it to a file, serve it to http request, etc.

Comment: how to do that I am trying same for long time

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-save-json-object-to-file-nodejs/

Comment: ok will try and will get back here if it doesn't work for my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233019/discussion-between-vamsee-and-isae).